# Getting id of created object similar to user>identity

Tags: yii, controller, yii2

When I create blog for user, before adding blog to database I can check user identity and get user ID, to write it in blogs database, so I know that this blog belongs to this user.

But What If I want to write a sub blog. In that case before starting adding it I need somehow parent blog ID in the controller. Can I get it the way $app->user->identity works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii::$app->user->identity holds the information of a logged in user and this is done automatically by Yii2 when you call the login() method of User object. So if you are asking if there's some way that you will get the parent blog ID automatically, then the answer is **No**.

However, there are several ways you can pass the parent blog ID to the controller action responsible for adding a sub blog. Following are some ways that come to mind:

1. I am assuming you will have some sort of a form where user will type the details of the sub blog. In this form you can have a drop down (mandatory field) showing the list of existing parent blogs (from `Blog` table). User must select a parent blog from this list and on submission of the form, inside the controller action you can easily write code to get the ID value of the parent blog from drop down.
2. Instead of having the user select the parent blog from drop down, you can pass the ID (as a query string parameter) of the parent blog when user clicks on a link/button to add a sub blog. And in the page with the form to add sub blog, you can set the parent blog ID from the query string into a hidden field. Finally, on submission of the form, inside the controller action you can easily write code to get the ID value of the parent blog from hidden input field.